# Where are Title, Author and Date?

Tags: titles

I've the following Example Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage[a4paper,top=1cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\title{Theorems And Proofs}
\author{Napoleone Bonaparte}
\date{May 2014}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

\section{Introduction}
Theorems can easily be defined

\theoremstyle{definition}
\begin{definition}{Fibration}
A fibration is a mapping between two topological spaces that has the homotopy lifting property for every space $X$.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ is 
a continuous function.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean theorem]
\label{pythagorean}
This is a theorema about right triangles and can be summarised in the next 
equation 
\[ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \]
\end{theorem}

And a consequence of theorem \ref{pythagorean} is the statement in the next 
corollary.

\begin{corollary}
There's no right rectangle whose sides measure 3cm, 4cm, and 6cm.
\end{corollary}

You can reference theorems such as \ref{pythagorean} when a label is assigned.

\begin{lemma}
Given two line segments whose lengths are $a$ and $b$ respectively there is a 
real number $r$ such that $b=ra$.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
To prove it by contradiction try and assume that the statemenet is false,
proceed from there and at some point you will arrive to a contradiction.
\end{proof}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but I don't understand because I dont see Title, Author and Date..

Comment: Try `\maketitle` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: `\author ` and friends just store the data in internal variables until you ask latex to typeset them, for example as yo' sats, by using `\maketitle`

Comment: @mle You're welcome. I just can't help myself, but this is some very basic knowledge. Have you read any LaTeX tutorial book or alike?

Comment: of course, but I forgot this particular, it can happen! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metadata are included in the document using the command `\maketitle`. Usually, it is the first thing after `\begin{document}`.